# Add text labels to photos

Tags: images

I have bunch of photos and I need to add graphic label to each of them (etc a place and date). I can do it via image editor, but it requires lots of efforts doing the same task of adding text, centering it, etc.

Labels are custom single-line text and provided by me, not taken from EXIF or so.

Is there a software that can help me with it?

Comment: Depends on what "etc." or "provided by me" is. You need to be  **as specific as possible** on this network.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with ImageMagick (freeware).  [See this link](https://imagemagick.org/Usage/text/) or [see this link](https://imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#label) for help adding custom text to image files.  ImageMagick also supports [batch processing](https://imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php).